# Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Go's C compiler?

Tags: c, go, cgo

So I'm porting [xxhash](http://code.google.com/p/xxhash/) from using cgo to Go's native 9p C, however I'm running into a rather weird problem.

The hash function works perfectly fine if called as a cgo function, however if I try to use the "native" version it returns the wrong hash.

I know enough C to get it working, but before reporting the issue, I want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/OneOfOne/fdab6439ea89871e0769)

**`xxhash.go`:**

```
//#include "xxhash_9p.c"
//import "C" //uncomment this and comment the next line for the cgo version
func XXH32_test(in unsafe.Pointer, l uint32, seed uint32) uint32


func GoXXH32(in []byte, seed uint32) (h uint32) {
    //omitted, full version in the gist above
}

func main() {
    b := []byte("ABCDEFGLAALSDLSD:LSDL:DL:DL:SDL:SL:DSL:DL:DSL:DL:{W{EOQWExzghp[[")
    fmt.Println(XXH32_test(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]), uint32(len(b)), 0)) //uncomment this and comment the next line for the cgo version
    //fmt.Println(C.XXH32_test(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]), C.uint(len(b)), 0))
    fmt.Println(GoXXH32(b, 0)) //this is tested against the C implementation and it's the right hash.
}
```

**`xxhash_9p.c`:**

```
#define PRIME32_1   2654435761U
#define PRIME32_2   2246822519U
#define PRIME32_3   3266489917U
#define PRIME32_4    668265263U
#define PRIME32_5    374761393U

#define U32 unsigned int
typedef struct _U32_S { U32 v; } U32_S;
#define A32(x) (((U32_S *)(x))->v)

U32 ·XXH32_test(const void* input, U32 len, U32 seed) {
//static U32 XXH32_test(const void* input, U32 len, U32 seed) {
    const char* p = (const char*)input;
    const char* bEnd = p + len;
    U32 h32;

    #define XXH_get32bits(p) A32(p)
    #define XXH_rotl32(x,r) ((x << r) | (x >> (32 - r)))

    if (len>=16) {
        const char* const limit = bEnd - 16;
        U32 v1 = seed + PRIME32_1 + PRIME32_2;
        U32 v2 = seed + PRIME32_2;
        U32 v3 = seed + 0;
        U32 v4 = seed - PRIME32_1;
        do
        {
            v1 += XXH_get32bits(p) * PRIME32_2; v1 = XXH_rotl32(v1, 13); v1 *= PRIME32_1; p+=4;
            v2 += XXH_get32bits(p) * PRIME32_2; v2 = XXH_rotl32(v2, 13); v2 *= PRIME32_1; p+=4;
            v3 += XXH_get32bits(p) * PRIME32_2; v3 = XXH_rotl32(v3, 13); v3 *= PRIME32_1; p+=4;
            v4 += XXH_get32bits(p) * PRIME32_2; v4 = XXH_rotl32(v4, 13); v4 *= PRIME32_1; p+=4;
        } while (p<=limit);

        h32 = XXH_rotl32(v1, 1) + XXH_rotl32(v2, 7) + XXH_rotl32(v3, 12) + XXH_rotl32(v4, 18);
    }
    else
    {
        h32  = seed + PRIME32_5;
    }

    h32 += (unsigned long) len;
    while (p<=bEnd-4) {
        h32 += XXH_get32bits(p) * PRIME32_3;
        h32  = XXH_rotl32(h32, 17) * PRIME32_4 ;
        p+=4;
    }

    while (p<bEnd) {
        h32 += (*p) * PRIME32_5;
        h32 = XXH_rotl32(h32, 11) * PRIME32_1 ;
        p++;
    }

    h32 ^= h32 >> 15;
    h32 *= PRIME32_2;
    h32 ^= h32 >> 13;
    h32 *= PRIME32_3;
    h32 ^= h32 >> 16;
    return h32;
}
```

Run:

```
$ go build && ./nocgo #9p native
134316512
981225178
$ go build && ./nocgo #cgo
981225178
981225178
```

**TL;DR:**

A C function returns the wrong value when used through Go's 6c, same exact C function returns the correct value when called through CGO.

//edit

I got a response on the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8454), it's not gonna get fixed and the 9p toolchain is going away eventually.

From **mi...@golang.org**:

> the C compiler will eventually go away. Plan for that, so don't rely
>   on it.
>
> Note the Plan 9 C compiler isn't fully ANSI compliant, and we're not
>   going to fix bugs in it (because we control both the compiler and its
>   input, we will just workaround its bugs).

Comment: you do know that the plan9 compiler is being removed from Go, right? I mean this might be interesting to figure out, but I wouldn't put much effort into porting something to 9p.

Comment: @Keith correct, I changed it. 
JimB I'm not even sure they will remove that completely, there's no official stance about it yet, and I know it's not gonna be removed in 1.4 at least. Only document I could find is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1P3BLR31VA8cvLJLfMibSuTdwTuF7WWLux71CYD0eeD8/edit

Comment: I don't know if 9p will be gone in 1.4, but I think it may be by 1.5. I know Russ has said that they plan to remove all non-gcc C from the source, and once that's done the plan9 compiler will be removed.

Comment: Somehow, the question seems incomplete.

Comment: Not really sure what's incomplete, the question is clear, why does the function return the wrong hash when called through 6c but returns the correct hash through cgo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, changing the function signature from

```
U32 ·XXH32_test(const void* input, U32 len, U32 seed)
```

to

```
void ·XXH32_test(const unsigned char* input, U32 len, U32 seed, U32 *ret)
```

And calling it like :

```
var u uint32
XXH32_test(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]), uint32(len(b)), 0, &u)
```

Returns the correct hash.

I'm still not sure what's going on, it *should* work how it originally was, but I'm guessing the runtime is doing some magic behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, it does. There is a document floating around the internet that describes this, but I don't know where it is. Please do not use the Plan9 C compiler for your own code.

Comment: Almost 50% speed improvements over cgo, oh well, such a shame.

Comment: @OneOfOne: try comparing them with a much larger input. The plan9 compiler isn't very well optimized, and cgo will likely win out when the go-cgo transition isn't as much of a factor.

Comment: I was using it for a project using `map[uint64-hash]*s`, so the input was usually around 30-100 bytes.